# Multiple XML files into dataframe in R

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, nodes

I have 155 xml files to be imported into R as a dataframe.
I know little about xml and am having trouble getting the nodes.

I wanted to write a function to get all the data in "d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC"

Here's my R code:

```
library(XML)
xml_to_df<-function(xmlfile){
  results <- xmlParse(xmlfile)
  df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(results, "//CardEpisodes/d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC"))
  return(df)
}
my_files<-list.files(pattern="\\.xml$")
my_data<-lapply(my_files,xml_to_df)
new_df<-bind_rows(my_data)
```

This code should be able to combine all my xml files in my working directory and put them into one dataframe.

The error that I got is:

> XPath error : Undefined namespace prefix
>   XPath error : Invalidexpression

I think my mistake should be in this line:

```
df <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(results, "//CardEpisodes/d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC"))
```

How should I set the nodes?

Thank you very much for your help!

[Edit]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CPRCard xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CPRcardViewer" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <CardEpisodes xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC>
         <d2p1:Key>0</d2p1:Key>
         <d2p1:Value>
            <AdqDepth>4</AdqDepth>
            <AdqRate>64</AdqRate>
            <AvgDepth>39</AvgDepth>
            <card z:Ref="i1"/>
         </d2p1:Value>
      </d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC>

      <d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC>
         <d2p1:Key>1</d2p1:Key>
            <d2p1:Value>
               <AdqDepth>17</AdqDepth>
               <AdqRate>28</AdqRate>
               <AvgDepth>45</AvgDepth>
               <card z:Ref="i1"/>
            </d2p1:Value>
      </d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC>
  </CardEpisodes>
</CPRCard>
```

Comment: Pls paste a copy-able sample of the xml file

Comment: @GGamba I have edited the post and added a copy-able sample of the xml file. I hid some data because it's too long. Is it fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing is the namespace definition, I'm not an expert but what the error is saying is "I don't know what that `d2p1` means". 
To avoid this you have to add a `namespaces` argument to the `getNodeSet` call:

```
getNodeSet(x, "//d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC", 
           namespaces = c(d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"))
```

I found the namespace specified in the complete xml.

---

Anyway inserting just this into the `xmlToDataFrame` function will cause problems, because the first level of the node is composed only by a `Key` and a `Value` field. The `Value` field then contains 3 data points.

```
xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(x,
                            "//d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC", 
                             c(d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")))
#  Key  Value
# 1   0  46439
# 2   1 172845
```

To avoid this we have to make two different call, one to retrive the 3 values and one for the key:

```
values <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(x,
                            "//d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC/d2p1:Value",
                            c(d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")))

keys <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(x, 
                            "//d2p1:KeyValueOfintEpisodesmiwmOyvC", 
                            c(d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")))
# Bind and clean
result <- data.frame(Key = keys[, 1], values[, 1:3])
```

---

Hope this helps